# How to implement the listener of Dynamically created button?

Tags: android, button

I have created button's dynamically by using RelativeLayout.Now i have to implement the listener of the dynamic button. How can i do this, And another thing i am creating multiple button's so plz tell me how can i do this?

This is my code

```
public class CreateButton extends Activity {

    int top=60,bottom=350, i;
    int s = 1,iddelete = 1,idedit=1;
    RelativeLayout rl;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.edit_r);

        // Create Bed Room
        Button Btn_BedRoom = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bed);
        Btn_BedRoom.setOnClickListener(ListenrOf_BedRoom);

    }

 // Listener Of Create Bed Room
    private OnClickListener ListenrOf_BedRoom = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CreateRoom();
            i+=35;
        }
    };


    public void CreateRoom()
    {       
        final Button delete = new Button(this);
        delete.setText("delete");
        delete.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);             
        lp.setMargins(120, top+i, 0, bottom-i);  
        delete.setHeight(5);
        delete.setWidth(5);
        delete.setLayoutParams(lp);
              delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CreateRoom();           
    }
    });                   
              rl.addView(delete);


        Button BtnEdit = new Button(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);             
        lp1.setMargins(150,top+i,0,bottom-i);
        BtnEdit.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edit);
        BtnEdit.setHeight(5);
        BtnEdit.setWidth(5);
        BtnEdit.getRight();
        BtnEdit.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        rl.addView(BtnEdit);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp2.setMargins(180,top+i,0,bottom-i);
        tv.setText("Bed Room " + s++);
        tv.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        rl.addView(tv);

    };


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Button bt = new Button(this.getApplicationContext());
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked
    }
});
```

Comment: Works perfect once you add the ) between the last } and ; :D

Answer (score 0):

Just call setOnClickListener for the buttons you have created, and pass in the click listener object you want.

Comment: Thanks for replay Dan i have implemented it but it is not working.

Comment: Well if its the delete and edit buttons that aren't working, I dont see you call `setOnClickListener` on either of them.  The `Btn_BedRoom` button should be working though

Comment: Thanks dude i got my mistake now its working i have posted my changed code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep a reference to those buttons, so that you can set the listener (`setOnClickListener()`) on them. You can set always the same listener of course, but in that case remember to set also a different id (`setId()`) for each button.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button mybutton = new Button(this);
mybutton.setText("My Button");
mybutton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: this will only work if the current class implements `OnClickListener` and overrides the `onClick()` method.